# Nginx server - 400 Bad Request

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, openssl, dockerfile

I am trying to launch my server with the SSL protocol, however I receive a big error message

"400 Bad Requests
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx/1.14.2"

I tried solutions like "ssl off" in the configuration file, but nothing changes, does anyone see a fault in my files?

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example;

    ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

And the Docker file :

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get -y install nginx \
    && apt-get install openssl

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl

RUN openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes \
        -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key \
        -out /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt \
        -subj "/C=FR/ST=IDF/L=Paris/O=42/OU=42/CN=example/UID=example"

COPY conf/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

EXPOSE 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port nginx` - when accessing use `https://domain.tld` and not `http://domain.tld:443`

Comment: @TelinovDmitri Okay, so in this case what would be the solution to resolve this problem ? And can you provide the command line for running the container with the good parameters please

Comment: You run it as usual, the problem appears when you are trying to access the container IP in browser or via CLI tools like `curl`

Comment: 42 Paris :p
To check out the config you can use `nginx -t`. From where are you trying to request the container? What is the commande line you write?

Comment: @CallMarl Oh nice ! Indeed 42P.
The commandline is : docker run -p 8080:443 serv

Comment: Then you are trying to access the docker container from the navigator?

Comment: @CallMarl Exactly

Comment: @CallMarl Now i got some privacy error

Comment: @CallMarl do you have discord ?